# Redirect a domain to a ip and port

Tags: node.js, redirect, port

I have a node.js server listening on port 4000

how can I redirect  my domain name: www.mydomain.com to a ip and port? The domain provider only allows an ip address without a portnumber in the redirection field. If I do a URL redirect, then the name of my side is not shown.

Please let me know how can I redirect it to my domain?

```
121.12.12.123:4000    redirect to   www.mydomain.com
```

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to do.  Please describe in more detail.  When a brower goes to XXX, what do you want to happen?

Comment: It's not your provider being difficult: DNS won't direct to a specific port. You might find that running a web page on port 80, with a redirect to port 4000 will do the job and keep your domain name.

Comment: Is a little complicated your question, What is what you want exactly? If you wanna to redirect a domain to an ip and port, you cant do that because is the job of the DNS, if you want to redirect a domain to your IP and port, you just put the port in the addres width a colon.

Comment: yeah but my  domain provider doesn't allow a colon in the ip input field

Comment: @Daniel answer is correct and works. You should mark it as solved.

Answer (score 5):

HTTP requests usually come in on port 80.  When you type in a domain and do not specify a port, it automatically connects to port 80.  You have a few options.  You can run your Node.js server as root and have it listen on port 80, but it's not recommended.

You can also setup a Nginx on port 80 and use it to reverse proxy requests to your Node.js process which is listening on port 4000, but this introduces another component in your stack to manage and introduces a little bit of overhead for each request.

The way I prefer to handle this is to setup a redirect in iptables (assuming you're using Linux).

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 4000
```

That will redirect all traffic from port 80 to port 4000, where you're listening Node.js process is.

That allows you to run your Node.js process as an unprivileged user, but still answer requests on port 80.

Once you've done that than you can simply point your domain to the IP address of the server and normal web requests should work.  Just be sure you have port 80 open on any firewalls first.

Comment: This really helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
httpProxy.createProxyServer({target:'http://localhost:4000'}).listen(80);
```